# Complete list of Google Gears enabled sites

Tags: google-gears

Is there a complete list of Google Gears enabled sites? I'm aware of rememberthemilk.com, google docs and google calendar

Comment: A complete list is an impossible task, even harder than "Give me a list of all active domain names in existence"

Comment: I think while complete is sort of impossible, we can always work on a list and see if others know more. For inspiration, as in what people built with it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySpace's message system is one of the *biggest* outside of Google. At least so I thought according to [this article](http://www.techcrunch.com/2008/05/28/myspace-shows-facebook-how-its-done-google-gears-to-power-messaging/).

Other sites are:

- [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com)
- [MindMeister](http://www.mindmeister.com/services/tools/offline)
- [PassPack](http://www.passpack.com/)
- [ZohoWriter](http://writer.zoho.com/)
- [BuxFer](http://buxfer.com/)
- [SomeThings](http://thn.gs/)

Answer (score 5):

So far it seems that:

- wordpress.com
- Zoho writer
- Buxfer
- PassPack
- Google Reader
- MindMeinster
- Google Picasa Web Albums
- MySpace (Mail Search)
- YouTube

Support Google Gears in some fashion. (list compiled from: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Gears), and [this site here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/web-applications-compatible-with-google-gears/1889/))

Answer (score 3):

Listed in the order of perceived decreasing complexity of offline implementation:

- Autodesk Labs Project Draw
- Buxfer
- Gmail
- Google Calendar
- Google Docs
- Google Reader
- MindMeinster
- Myspace
- Paymo
- Passpack
- Picasa Web Albums
- Remember The Milk
- Some Things
- WordPress
- Zoho Mail
- Zoho Writer

Taken from:
http://tarunupadhyay.com/2009/06/15/full-list-of-websites-that-you-can-take-offline-with-google-gears/

Answer (score 2):

Gmail [now uses Gears](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/07/gmail-and-google-calendar-to-add.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

[Remember The Milk](http://rememberthemilk.com)